# Android click event div element

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I am having the following issue with click/touchstart event on Android (as far as I know only happening on Android),
1. the element triggers a modal window.
2. one of the buttons/links inside this modal gets triggered instantly without giving the user the option to make a choice.

It is of course required for the visitor/user to view the modal content before being redirected to a link to another page from one of those buttons.

I believe this is due to the 'touchstart' event bind to this div, which I am using since click events on divs for touch devices don't work.

I am using jQuery to make this work, and on iOS there doesn't seem to appear any issue.

```
$(document).on('click touchstart','.mydiv', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // open modal
});
```

Any suggestions please.

Comment: this should work what you've written above. But still you can try adding `e.stopPrapagation()` in case this is caused b some bubbling of events

Comment: @GeorgeBailey, sorry this doesn't fix it either. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(.mydiv).on('touchstart', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
   // open modal
});
```

cheers

Comment: There is no reason why this should work in comparison with the above code.